# Check if datetime object is present in database

Tags: python, django

I've got a database in Django that's handling venue bookings as follows:

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

Whenever a booking is created it stores the start and end times for that venue.

Now, on the next booking, in my views I need to check if a the incoming start_time is already present or falls between other time slots that are already booked.

```
def add_booking(request):
    user = UserProfile.objects.get(user__pk=request.user.id)
    if 'start_time' in request.POST:
        start_time = request.POST['start_time']
    if 'end_time' in request.POST:
        end_time = request.POST['end_time']
    #logic for checking if start_time is already booked.
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if there are any bookings with a start time earlier or the same as your requested start and an end time later or the same as the requested start:

```
Booking.objects.filter(start_date__lte=start_time, end_date__gte=start_time).count()
```

If that comes back as 0 then the start time isn't already booked.

Comment: Relevant Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#filtered-querysets-are-unique